# abstract class with more then one parameterized constructor and derived class with parameterized constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public class ParentBaseClass
{
    public ParentBaseClass()
    {
        // Parameter less constructor
    }
    public ParentBaseClass(string type)
    {
        // single parameter constructor
    }
    public ParentBaseClass(Entity model)
    {
        // entity type constructor
    }
    public ParentBaseClass(string type, bool IsNewEntity)
    {
        // two parameter constructor
    }
    public ParentBaseClass(string type, bool IsNewEntity, Entity model)
    {
        // three parameter constructor
    }
}

public class ChildClassFirst : ParentBaseClass
{
    public ChildClassFirst() : base("Customer", false)
    {
        // implementation of 4th constructor having string, bool parameters.
    }
}
```

in child class I implemented only one constructor of parent class having two parameters. why there no need to implement other constructor? can anyone explain me? please consider other constructor may have MVC Model class or other entity class of dbContext.

Comment: As long as any base class constructor (including an automatically generated default constructor, if applicable) will be implicitly or explicitly called by the base class, then no other constructor calls are required.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWatson

Comment: Correction to my statement: Change "called by the base class" to "called by the derived class". (But I think you got my meaning)

Answer (score 0):

Every child class calls it's base class constructor, if there is a parameter-less constructor and we haven't implemented any parameter based constructor in it, the parameter-less is automatically called, but like in your case you are specifying which constructor to be used when `ChildClassFirst` is instantiated, so now the calling code has only access to this parameter-less constructor to instantiate an object of `ChildClassFirst` which in turn will instantiate the parent class object using the parameter based constructor which is called using `base()`.

In short, Child class only needs to specify one base class construction which would be called during instantiation of child class, and when there is none specified the default would be parameter-less constructor which would get called, but remember the parameter-less only exists if we have no parameterized constructor specified in the class.

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan Sajjad

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are designed for inheritance by other classes, usually more than one. Different derived classes may need to construct their abstract base class in slightly different ways. Hence, an abstract class can supply different constructors for different derived classes.

Non-abstract derived classes, on the other hand, are designed to be instantiated by the class users. User construction needs may be completely different from the needs of the class itself, so derived classes provide their own constructors.

Therefore, the two sets of constructors are completely independent of each other: they serve different needs. Derived classes can provide more or fewer constructors, and the signatures of their constructors may be similar or completely different. This is exactly the case in your code: `ChildClassFirst` provides a parameterless constructor, while its abstract base class provides two constructors with different sets of parameters. As long as you provide any constructor in the derived class, C# compiler is fine with your code.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight